# p:cellEditor does not save textarea onblur when clicking a link

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Saving a text inside a `p:cellEditor > p:inputTextarea` works perfectly `onblur` when clicking outside the cell.
However when clicking on a link (e.g. commandButton, commandLink) coming from a `p:cellEditor > p:inputTextarea` it does not execute the `p:ajax` `cellEdit` event beforehand. It instead executes the clicked link.

This is not correct since it works for `p:inputTextarea` without a `p:cellEditor`. I realize this might as well be a Primefaces bug. Any idea how to work around this?

```
<p:dataTable>

    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{bean.onCellEdit}" />

    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
          <h:outputText    value="#{model.text}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
          <p:inputTextarea value="#{model.text}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>

<p:dataTable>

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.someOtherAction}" />
```

I submitted the bug to Primefaces. But is there a workaround for this via javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After no success on the Primefaces bug report I ended up hooking up the listener to all of the `p:cellEditor` instances directly. It seems to work and I'm not losing inputs anymore.

```
<p:cellEditor>
    <f:facet name="output">
      <h:outputText    value="#{model.text}" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">
      <p:inputTextarea value="#{model.text}">
      <!-- this is the relevant line -->
      <p:ajax listener="#{bean.onCellEdit}" global="false" update="@this" />
      <!-- end relevant line -->
      </p:inputTextarea>
    </f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
```

Comment: After hours of trying out different things, yours was the only solution that worked, although I'm still not clear how. Can you add your primefaces bug ID here so I can track it? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I did quite similar but without `<p:cellEditor>`. In that mode that did not work for me.
But if you use just

```
<p:column>
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{listElement.field1}">
<p:ajax listener="#{bean.saveAction}" global="false" update="@this"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</p:column>
<p:column>
<p:inputTextarea value="#{listElement.field2}">
<p:ajax listener="#{bean.saveAction}" global="false" update="@this"/>
</p:inputTextarea>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```